# Can I make a phone call from my iOS app, which is not currently active?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, background-process

I have a bluetooth device which is connected to the iPhone and has a control button. Pressing this button should make the app to perform a phone call to the previously defined number and establish a voice connection with the device (like bluetooth headset).

From what I've learned, it's not a problem when the app is active, but if it's not? 99% of the time it will be in suspended state. Documentation says, that a bluetooth device can wake up the app from suspended state to perform some data processing etc. But I couldn't find the info about phone calls.

As I understand it, the app can be waken up and perform a phone call, but this is critically important and I need to know for sure, so any information on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: u cannot send a call when app is in background..try using push notifications, and if the user taps on the notification, u can send the call function from your app

Comment: not an option. it's vital for the bluetooth device to be able to initiate a call, like handset does

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the app to perform the call when it's not active. Instead, you should use Apple's handsfree protocol for bluetooth to perform the call on the bluetooth device itself.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks! Is it possible to setup bluetooth device to call certain number? And the app should have the ability to change this number.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you can find something in Apple's Documentation for Bluetooth devices (also, take a look at ANSC)